# Backpropagation always pushes network to the same outputs no matter the parameters

Tags: c++, neural-network, backpropagation

I have been working on adding backpropagation to my neural network code I wrote a while back, after adding and triple checking all the math I have reached the conclusion that it doesn't work. The network always outputs the same thing with very little care for what the input is. [The code](https://replit.com/@JheranBull/c-neuralnet?v=1) can be seen here (the <> button in the top right has to be pressed to show the files, the whole project was too large to put in here).

So to expand on exactly what's happening, whenever I add the deltas to the weights/biases the network always ends up reaching a output like `Correct: 1, 0, Predicted: 0.996989, 0.953245`. Outputting the same two high numbers even in the opposite input case. So I checked my math (notepad visible below) and it came out right, decreasing the error in the following run.

> w1 .9
> b1 .3
> w2 1.3
> b2 0.1
>
> (Correct output is 1 if i1 > 2, otherwise its 0)
> i1 = input, a = (w * layerinput) + b, z = sigmoid(a), e = (correct - output)^2
>
> i1 = 3
> a1 = 3
> z1 = .952
>
> a2 = 1.338
> z2 = .7922
>
> e = .0431
>
> z2/e = -.7491
> a2/z2 = 0.2179
>
> w2/e = .2074
> b2/e = .2179
>
> z1/a2 = .28327
> a1/z1 = 0.24505
>
> w1/e = .73515
> b1/e = .24505
>
> --post adjust (with a epsilon of .1)--
>
> w1 .973515
> b1 .324505
> w2 1.32074
> b2 0.12179
>
> i1 = 3
> a1 = 3.24505
> z1 = 0.962494833445
>
> a2 = 1.3929954263241493
> z2 = 0.801070015356
>
> e = .039601

Using the simplified test (if input > 2 then output = 1 else output = 0) and network I tested the code, it worked fine with the same input my math check used but when I gave it a diff input it still had positive deltas (and raised its output), so I'm assuming it's a problem with my code. And that's where I'm asking for help, I've looked over my code multiple times and have been unable to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Please show a [mre] for your code in the question itself. Questions are supposed to be self-contained without the need to visit external links. Also, the question seems too general. You should try to debug your code yourself. If you have a specific C++ question as a result of your debugging session, you can ask about here, but debugging your specific program isn't going to be helpful to other users.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the response! I'll adjust the question to those standards when I'm back at my pc.

Comment: The first thing is to check that derivatives are calculated correctly. Simple finite difference check could be very useful to find derivative-related bugs.